# Inheritance: Unable to access method from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, cqrs

I am implementing CQRS pattern. To use CQRS pattern in my project I wrote three commands, they are

```
public class DogCommand : PetCommand
{
    public DogCommand(){}
    public override string Name{get; set;}
}

public class CatCommand : PetCommand
{
    public CatCommand(){}
    public override string Name{get; set;}
}

public abstract class PetCommand : ICommand
{
    public PetCommand(){}
    public virtual string Name{get; set;}
}

public interface ICommand
{
   //Business logic
 }
```

Here I have interface called `ICommand`. PetCommand is base class which is implementing this interface. Derived class `DogCommand` and `CatCommand` are inheriting `PetCommand`.

I also wrote base command handler, as below

```
public abstract class BaseCommandHandler<T> : CommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    protected BaseCommandHandler(string type, string name): base(type, name)
    {

    }
}
public abstract class CommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
   protected CommandHandler(string type, string name)
   {
    //Business logic
   }

   protected void LogWrite(T command)
   {
      //Writing log 
   }
}


public interface ICommandHandler<in T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Run(T command);
}
```

All functions present in `BaseCommandHandler`, I will use in each derived command handler

Now problem is in derived class command handler

```
public class PetCommandHandler : BaseCommandHandler<DogCommand>, ICommandHandler<CatCommand> 
{

    public void Run(DogCommand dCommand)
    {
        this.LogWrite(dCommand)      
    }

    public void Run(CatCommand cCommand)
    {
       **//Want to access this.LogWrite() with cCommand. How can I do that?**          
    }
}
```

Here I am unable to access `this.LogWrite()` function for cCommand, because `PetCommandHandler` is inheriting *first* `BaseCommandHandler` and *then* implementing ICommandHandle.

> How to access `this.LogWrite()` function for cCommand?

Here is compile time error:

> cannot convert from ‘Command.DogCommand’ to ‘Command.CatCommand’

---

**Update :**

**First way to fix this issue :**

I can fix this issue by using base command i.e `PetCommand` in `BaseCommandHandler` instead of `DogCommand`. This will help me to access all derived classes in `this.LogWrite()` function, but this will lead me to implement empty `Run(PetCommand petCommand) {}` function, that I don't want to do.

**Second way :**

I can change `LogWrite()` function as `virtual` in `CommandHandler` and `override` whenever I face this situation.

I really appreciate if someone provide me any other solution for this issue.

Comment: `PetCommandHandler` is trying to have two Pet Type, why?

Comment: Um, there is no overload of `LogWrite` shown here that accepts either `DogCommand` or `CatCommand`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to 'fake' multiple inheritance. I'd just create a `DogCommandHandler` and a `CatCommandHandler`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Yes because `PetCommandHandler` will support all `PetCommands`. I can not write separate command handler for each command which deried from `PetCommand`.

Comment: The code does not have LogWrite method which accepts DogCommand or CatCommand as argument.

Comment: @DavidG, Writing two different command handler will resolve my issue I agree. Can we implement it in single Command handler

Comment: Yes, write the `PetCommandHandler` to take a `PetCommand`.

Comment: You should have only in one command handler which accepts ICommand or PetCommand as T. Current design will not work when you create another class inheriting from PetCommand class.

Comment: @DavidG, Yes I can achieve in that way, but I need to write `Run()` function for `PetCommand` then

Comment: Exactly, yes. The command handler should deal with a pet, not just a cat or a dog. If you need specific cat functionality then you need a cat handler. (see the L in SOLID principles)

Comment: @DavidG, I updated my question with my attempts to solve this issue

Comment: I don't understand why `Run(PetCommand` would be an empty method.

Comment: @DavidG Because `Run(T command);` is an abstract method in interface `ICommandHandler<in T>`. When ever I use `PetCommand` instead of `T`, then compiler will force me to write definition of `Run(T command)` for `PetCommand`. Right now I don't have any logic to write `Run()` for `PetCommand`. In future I am not going to write any thing related to pet command. I just used `PetCommand` to store comman properties of `DogCommand` and `CatCommand`

Comment: You either need a separate cat and dog commands or a pet command, any other route you take is going to violate good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a design issue to resolve.

You are trying to handle Two separate Types in the generic class. This is not a extensible design.

When there will be a new class inheriting from `PetCommand` created, you will have to change PetCommand handler class to implement interface  `ICommandHandler<newPetCommand>`. That's basically a bad design.

The command handler class of yours should deal with the Pet, not with a specific type of Pet such as Cat or Dog.

You need to have CommandHandler and PetCommandHandler class as following.

```
public abstract class CommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    protected CommandHandler(string type, string name)
    {
        //Business logic
    }

    //Making Run method abstract so that 
    //individual Handler class can have their own logic in it.
    public abstract void Run(T command);

    //Common implementation for LogWrite.
    //If this also requires override, it can be made virtual 
    //so that deriving class can override the logic.
    protected void LogWrite(T command)
    {
        //Writing log 
    }
}

//PetCommandHandler class now can be used for any class object 
//which is inheriting PetCommand class.
public class PetCommandHandler<T> : BaseCommandHandler<T> where T: PetCommand
{
    public PetCommandHandler(string type, string name) : base(type, name)
    {

    }

    public override void Run(T dCommand)
    {
        this.LogWrite(dCommand);
    }
}
```

How to test?

```
var dog = new DogCommand();
var commandHandler = new PetCommandHandler<DogCommand>("Dog", "Tom");
commandHandler.Run(dog);

var cat = new CatCommand();
var catHandler = new PetCommandHandler<CatCommand>("Cat", "Mini");
catHandler.Run(cat);
```

If you later introduce new `PetCommand` class, let say `PandaCommand`. You can still use PetHandler as following.

```
var pandaHandler = new PetHandler<PandaCommand>("Panda", "Po");
var panda = new PandaCommand();
pandaHandler.Run(panda);
```

If you do not want to create separate instance of `PetCommandHandler` for different PetCommand type. You can change the PetCommandHandler class as following.

```
public class PetCommandHandler : BaseCommandHandler<PetCommand>
{
    public PetCommandHandler(string type, string name) : base(type, name)
    {

    }
    public override void Run(PetCommand dCommand)
    {
        this.LogWrite(dCommand);
    }
}
```

With this class you just need to create only one instance of `PetCommndHandler` and you can execute `Run` method with any object of PetCommand

```
var patCommandHandler = new PetCommandHandler("someType", "someName");
patCommandHandler.Run(dog);
patCommandHandler.Run(cat);
patCommandHandler.Run(panda);
```

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: For rest of the commands, I am using your last option. For `Pet` I have different implementations. I will go forward and will follow your last option for my most of the commands. For `DogCommand` and `CatCommand` (Which contains some special features) I will write separate command handler instead of doing it in same `CommandHandler`. Thanks for your time and efforts. I am accepting your answer which covered my all scenarios